# Combine two column into one

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I have table like

```
Tabel data
+-------+-------+
| name1 | name2 |
+-------+-------+
| AA    | XX    |
| BB    | YY    |
| CC    | ZZ    |
+-------+-------+
```

and I want the output like

```
Edit
+-------+
| name1 |
+-------+
| AA    |
| XX    |
| BB    |
| YY    |
| CC    |
| ZZ    |
+-------+
```

can u please guide me to query to obtain this task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` or `UNION` . `UNION` will create a `DISTINCT` result Set. If you don't want, you can use `UNION ALL`, which will simply concat the data

```
SELECT NAME1 as NAME FROM YOUR_TABLE
UNION
SELECT NAME2 FROM YOUR_TABLE
ORDER BY NAME
```

**EDIT:** For your updated requirements

```
with my_data(name1,name2) as
(
  select 'AA','XX' from dual
  union
  select 'BB','YY' from dual
  union
  select 'CC','ZZ' from dual
),
indexed_my_data(name1,name2,row_sequence) as
(
  select name1,name2, row_number() over (order by null) from my_data
)
select name1,row_sequence,'A' as col_sequence from indexed_my_data
union all
select name2,row_sequence,'B' from indexed_my_data
ORDER BY row_sequence,col_sequence;
```

Comment: @RakaWidjaya For this, you have to go with analytical functions. Generate a sequence numbe for every row, to maintain the order and a column sequence too.

Comment: i'm very thankful that you are considering my problem